# Traversing a hierarchy on Azure SQL from a natively compiled stored procedure

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, hierarchical-data, memory-optimized-tables

I have a simple self referencing in-memory table

```
CREATE TABLE [Accounts]
(
  Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
  [ParentAccount_Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Accounts] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id])
)  
WITH  
(
  MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON,  
  DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA
);
```

I'm struggling to find an elegant way to traverse the hierarchy represented by the table i.e. given an Account.Id I need to fetch a list of it's ancestors.

Ordinarily, when not using natively compiled sprocs, I would use either a CTE or the HIERARCHYID data type. However, neither of these are supported for natively compiled sprocs.

So my questions is, what technique can I use to traverse this hierarchy that is compatible with natively compiled stored procedures?

Sample data and expected results:

```
|Id                                     |ParentAccounts_Id                     |
|---------------------------------------|--------------------------------------|
|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000006   |00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002  |
|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000005   |00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002  |
|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004   |00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001  |
|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003   |00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001  |
|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002   |00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001  |
|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001   |NULL                                  |
```

Given the initial Id is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000006 I would expect to see the follow result

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000006
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) Create a normal stored procedure.  Normal (or non-natively compiled code) running against in-memory tables is called 'interop' and there's no real reason this wouldn't be fast:

```
DECLARE @id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000006'

;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT 1 xlevel, Id, ParentAccount_Id
FROM dbo.accounts
WHERE Id = @id

UNION ALL

SELECT xlevel + 1, a.Id, a.ParentAccount_Id
FROM cte c
    INNER JOIN dbo.accounts a ON c.ParentAccount_Id = a.Id
)
SELECT Id
FROM cte
```

Or, 2) implement a loop in the natively compiled procedure.  If you take a look at this example [I did with Fizzbuzz](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/87488/11537), it's lightning fast - under a second for 1 million loops.

```
DROP PROC IF EXISTS dbo.usp_getAccounts
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS dbo.typ_accounts
GO

CREATE TYPE dbo.typ_accounts
AS TABLE
(
    Id                  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ( Id )
)
WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON ); 
GO


DROP PROC IF EXISTS dbo.usp_getAccounts
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.usp_getAccounts

    @targetAccountId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

WITH
    NATIVE_COMPILATION, 
    SCHEMABINDING, 
    EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN ATOMIC
WITH
(
    TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SERIALIZABLE, 
    LANGUAGE = N'english'
)   

    DECLARE @t AS dbo.typ_accounts;

    WHILE ( @targetAccountId IS NOT NULL )
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @t ( Id )
        SELECT @targetAccountId;

        SELECT @targetAccountId = ParentAccount_Id
        FROM dbo.Accounts
        WHERE Id = @targetAccountId;

    END

    SELECT Id
    FROM @t;

    RETURN;

END
GO


EXEC dbo.usp_getAccounts '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000006'
```

What sort of volumes do you have?  Is there a specific reason you are using in-memory tables?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I've come up with that is compatible with natively compiled stored procedures is the following:

```
DECLARE @targetAccountId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000006'
WHILE (@targetAccountId IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    PRINT @targetAccountId

    SELECT @targetAccountId = ParentAccounts_Id
            FROM [im].[Accounts]
            WHERE Id = @targetAccountId
END
```

Although I'm open to better ideas as seeing loops in T-SQL always gives me shivers!